# How to run javaFlightRecorder on jar file

Tags: java, jfr

I have a Compiled java program as jar file. Can I run jfr on jar files? how?

Can I specify what I want to benchmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running JDK 11, or later, and want the file dump when the program ends:

```
$ java -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=dump.jfr -jar benchmark.jar
```

You can then open up the file in [JMC](https://jdk.java.net/jmc/8/) to see information about garbage collection, allocation, hot methods etc.

Comment: I run it as `$ java -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=dump.jfr -jar benchmark.jar parameters_for_jar`  and theirs an error     Error: Could not find or load main class XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=dump.jfr Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=dump.jfr

Comment: Should work. In the error message, it looks like "-" is missing in front XX:StartFlightRecording

Comment: yes, i missed that. Thanks!!!